# Does my secondary attack use up my standard action for my turn?

Tags: dnd-4e, combat, powers

> **Visions of Avarice**
>
> Daily - Arcane, Illusion, Implement, Zone Standard Action
> Area burst 5 within 10 squares
>
> Effect: The burst creates a
> zone in its origin square. The zone lasts until the end of your next
> turn. You then make the primary attack.
>
> Primary Target: Each enemy in the burst
> Primary Attack: Intelligence vs. Will
> Hit: You pull the
> primary target up to 4 squares toward the zone. If the primary target
> is then in the zone or adjacent to it, the primary target is
> immobilized (save ends).
>
> Sustain Minor: The zone persists until the
> end of your next turn, and you make the secondary attack.
>
> Secondary Attack
> Close burst 5 centered on the zone
> Secondary Target: Each enemy in the burst
> Attack: Intelligence vs. Will
> Hit: You pull the secondary target up to 4 squares toward the zone

On Turn One, I use my standard action to create the zone. Then, I attempt to pull each enemy in the burst into the zone.

On Turn Two, I use my minor action to sustain the zone. Now it will last until the end of Turn Three.

My question is whether on Turn Two it takes my standard action to perform the secondary attack or if it's included in the minor action.

Answer (score 13):

**You do not use actions to make the secondary attack.**

The secondary attack happens automatically when you sustain the power:

> Sustain Minor: The zone persists until the end of your next turn, and you make the secondary attack.

There's no *other* way to make the secondary attack (it only happens when you sustain, and you can only sustain once per round).

Answer (score 4):

**No. It's a part of the sustain minor, not another standard action**

The online compendium has this broken down a bit better than you've got it here and clearly states that it is a minor action:

```
Visions of Avarice Attack

The illusion of a fabulous treasure appears out of thin air. Your enemies throw aside caution to seize it.

Daily      Arcane, Illusion, Implement, Zone
Minor Action      Close burst 5 centered on the zone

Requirement: The Visions of Avarice power must be active to use this power.

Secondary Target: Each enemy in the burst

Attack: Intelligence vs. Will

Hit: You pull the secondary target up to 4 squares toward the zone.
```

Ultimately the "sustain minor: make a secondary attack" should tell you it does not consume a standard.